# $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path returning NULL

Tags: powershell

I have the following code as the beginning of a longer script:

```
$ScriptPath = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
& $ScriptPath\build_functions.ps1
& $ScriptPath\build_builddefs.ps1
```

The idea is to get the path of the script being run and use that path to call some supporting scripts. However when I went to test this out in isolation to make sure it could work (by highlighting that block and running just that code), I got the following error:

```
Split-Path: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

Interestingly enough, when I run the entire script it seems to run these files separately. Is there something I'm missing about how the ISE handles running a selection rather than the full script? Does it not establish a file system context when you run a selection?

Comment: $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path will only return path if called from the $script: scope . See [$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path is $null in PowerGUI script editor](//stackoverflow.com/a/2990762) . Consider other way to [What's the best way to determine the location of the current PowerShell script?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5466329)

Comment: I fixed my problem: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/why-pscommandpath-is-null-in-ise-or-powergui/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`$MyInvocation` is an [automatic variable](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html) populated at **script run time**, then if you execute `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` in a `powershell console` or `ISE` isn't populated;

that's why in your test the `$ScriptPath` has no value (`$null`)

Comment: $MyInvocation is most definitely populated in ISE, but it is not populated fully when called from inside local function, at least thats my quick assumption from my testing.
Using instead `$PSCommandPath` and `$PSScriptRoot` for powershell 3.0+

Comment: It is populated normally in ISE when you click "Run Script" but it is not populated when you click "Run Selection", and it is not populated when you click "Run Script" on a new file that has not been saved yet.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't if what happened to me was why some where seeking null in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path, but I will explain how I found the solution.**

I had scripts that were working in production, yet when I loaded the .ps1 file up and tried to get $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path it was null. My version of Powershell was 4.0, but 1.0 for the ISE (%windir%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell_ISE.exe).

But it didn't occur to me at first why they should work, yet when I manually inspected $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path or $MyInvocation in PowerShell why it was null, and why I was getting a null error for Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path.

So I thought I needed to upgrade the powershell to 5.1 on my Windows 2012 R2 Server like on my desktop NUC PC.

The real problem was that I found that if I set a break point in my .ps1 file and ran it to the spot where I was doing:

> $ScriptDir = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

That it worked. Of course it worked, I had been using it for a while. Why didn't I see it before?

What went wrong? I was trying to manually run the PowerShell in pieces using the run step command, when I had never run the script before since PowerShell was open!

**I have to say this is probably a No Duh moment.**

But we had recently had a server crash and had it restored (VSphere Clustered) and reseeded, so I thought maybe I have an older version of PowerShell.

PowerShell allows you to have multiple files/windows open inside it, yet the variables are shared between them. Apparently until you actually try to run the script (not step by step run), it has no script file executing and can't get you the path.

**I hope this post saves someone from wasting a bunch of time like I did!**

Answer (score 0):

i think you need write just:
& .\MySuperDuperScript.ps

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the other remarks, I got it to work inside a function as:

`Split-Path -Path $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent`

Just put the "Script:" in front of MyInvocation ...