# How do I fix couple of errors - generating SQL Script

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

Trying to create a SQL script for user migrations from On-Prem SQL DB to Azure SQL. Getting the following two errors. Noob here, any assistance would be appreciated as its been really exhausting to figure this thing out.

Split-Path: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
New-UserMigrationSQL:
Line |
10 |      -TargetServerSQLAdminPassword "$Manager1" `
|                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
| Cannot bind argument to parameter 'TargetServerSQLAdminPassword' because it is an empty string.

```
 $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
 $PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
 Import-Module C:\Cloud\GeneratePostCloudMigrationSql.psm1 -Force



 New-UserMigrationSQL `
-SourceServer "mysourceSQL Database Server name" `
-SourceDatabase "mysource database" `
-SourceServerSQLAdminUsername "admin" `
-SourceServerSQLAdminPassword "admin password" `
-targetCloudProvider "Azure" `
-TargetServer "test.database.windows.net" `
-TargetDatabase "test_migration" `
-TargetServerSQLAdminUsername "admin" `
-TargetServerSQLAdminPassword "admin password" `
-QueryTimeout 120 `
-TargetDomain "@mydomain.com" `
-TargetDomainType "AAD" `
-usernameConversionMap $usernameConversionMap `
-outputDirForGeneratedSql "./generatedSQL/"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is caused by using `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` on command line. That [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7) is assigned a value only when running a .ps1 script file. Also, see [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18742456/503046) about the same problem.

The second one claims that the variable containing admin password doesn't exist. By the error, it should be

```
-TargetServerSQLAdminPassword "$Manager1"
```

but the code pasted has different content:

```
-TargetServerSQLAdminPassword "admin password"
```

It's likely the admin password variable is either not initialized or its name is mis-spelled. To catch this kind of errors, use strict mode. It will make Powershell to give an error message should non-initialized variable be used.

```
set-strictmode -version 'latest'
```